# How to open default email app inbox in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app and am trying to open the the default mail client directly to the Inbox.

I'm able to open and pass data through to compose a message using XF Essentials

```
Email.ComposeAsync(message);
```

But I would like the app to open the default mail app's Inbox on a button press. Is this possible in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31594815/7432494), you would have to implement it on your android project and then using it via [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw both answers when I cam into work this morning. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) is what you need.
Create an interface in your Forms project:

```
public interface IOpenManager
{
    void openMail();
}
```

Then implement it on each platform, for iOS:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenImplementation))]
namespace Demo.iOS
{
    public class OpenImplementation : IOpenManager
    {
        public void openMail()
        {
            NSUrl mailUrl = new NSUrl("message://");
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(mailUrl))
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(mailUrl);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

For Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenImplementation))]
namespace Demo.Droid
{
    public class OpenImplementation : IOpenManager
    {
        public void openMail()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
            intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryAppEmail);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

At last, call this dependcy via: `DependencyService.Get<IOpenManager>().openMail();`

Comment: Thank you!! I struggled to find anything useful but this is exactly what I need.