# How to open default email app - inbox in iOS from an xamarin forms app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I checked out this topic before I decided to post a question :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077996/how-to-open-default-email-app-inbox-in-xamarin-forms)

While Depedency Service works on Android, I have some diffculties on my iOS part.
I added UrlType "message://" to info plist.info
So Im getting into if section:

```
    {
        public void openMail()
        {
            NSUrl mailUrl = new NSUrl("message://");
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(mailUrl))
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(mailUrl);
            }            
        }
    }
```

but nothing really happens afterwards..application doesnt crash, just it does nothing.

I wanted to check if the `message://` is a good qualifier for calling an app (default email client)?

Comment: you don't need to use DependencyService to do this.  Look at the linked question, or use Xamarin Essentials - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?tabs=ios

Comment: but I dont want to send mail, I want just to open an inbox?

Comment: are you testing this on a real device or the simulator?

Comment: on emulator, on real device its working now. thanks!

Comment: the iOS emulator does not have an e-mail app