# How to open mail inbox in react native with Linking.openURL

Tags: react-native

Hello my name is Rajdeep singh. I want to ask that how to open the gmail inbox in react native with Linking.openURL command.

Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch and open email client React-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594818/how-to-launch-and-open-email-client-react-native)

Comment: Do you want to say open the Gmail client app instead of the default email client?

Comment: Yes I want to open the gmail client app

Answer (score 1):

Read this - [How to launch and open email client React-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594818/how-to-launch-and-open-email-client-react-native)

React Native Open Mail Function

```
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com') }
  title="support@example.com" />
```

React Native Open Mail Function With Subject and Body

```
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description') }
  title="support@example.com" />
```